# Most elegant way to prove $1-2\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I verify that
$$1-2\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1$$
Is true for all $x$?

It can be proved through a couple of messy steps using the fact that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, solving for one of the trigonemtric functions and then substituting, but the way I did it gets very messy very quickly and you end up with a bunch of factoring, etc.

What's the simplest way to solve this?

Comment: Best to define, in objective terms, how you define "messy", vs. "most elegant?"  This is, as a question, asking for an answer, which is necessarily based on your personal opinion, and the answers based on the answerers' personal opinion.

Comment: Also, please include your workings (your work that you refer to in the clause "but the way I did it gets messy very quickly and you end up....".)  That gives answerers a baseline:  "the asker did this: ..... and considers it too messy,"  from which they can answer in anyway better than that.

Answer (score 3):

$$1=\cos^2x+\sin^2x$$
$$2=2\cos^2x+2\sin^2x$$
$$2-2\sin^2x=2\cos^2x$$
$$1-2\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1$$

Answer (score 2):

Given $$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$
we rearrange to get
$$\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$$
Substituting:
$$1-2\sin^2(x)=1-2(1-\cos^2(x))=2\cos^2(x)-2+1=2\cos^2(x)-1$$
Perhaps not as messy as you imagined.

Answer (score 2):

Both are equal to $\cos 2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$ by the duplication formula!

If you don't want to use this formula, just rewrite the equality as
$$1+1=2\sin^2x+2\cos^2x $$
and it boils down to *Pythagoras' identity*.

Answer (score 1):

It should be very nice: $1-2\sin^{2}\theta=1-2(1-\cos^{2}\theta)=1-2+2\cos^{2}\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the trigonometric functions on one side and integers on the other. Then, divide by $2$ to get $\sin{x^2}+\cos{x}^2 = 1.$ Since we know this to be true (check out proof of unit circle), we have hereby finished our proof!